# Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'GoogleMobileAds' after swift 2 conversion

Tags: swift2, cocoapods, xcode7

Good day everyone. So i just migrated to swift 2.0 and am facing this problem as titled: Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'GoogleMobileAds'. 21 occurrences. What I have done so far:

I removed every item on my pod file and reinstalled one at a time. Just before adding the GoogleMobileAds, everything would work and deploy to the simulator. Once I add it in, I see all these errors.

I have tried:

- "Allow non-modular Includes in Framework Modules" to "Yes".
- I added    the "post_install" script for
  "'CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES'" to "yes" at
  the pod file.

Strange thing was it did work for half a day on the simulator. When i was ready to deploy to device, it stopped working. I decided to reinstall the pods and it doesnt work even on simulator again.

Please help.

Attached some screen shots:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: My temporary solution is to remove the post_install script in the pod file above, I removed Google-Mobile-Ads-Sdk from cocoapods all together. I added the framework manually by downloading at https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/download. This step is followed by adding the framework path at "Targets"-"Build Settings"-"Search Paths"-"Framework Search Paths"

Answer (score 1):

I have faced a similar situation as yours.
In my case, the following steps solved the issue.

1. Re-installed AdMob SDK after removing it once using command 'pod install'.
   *This step may not be needed. I'm not sure.
2. Added the following line to my bridging-Header file.

   #import <GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds.h>

   You might have to create the file into your project manually if you don't have it. The file's name is [Your project name]-Bridging-Header.h  for example, MyApp-Bridging-Header.h

   You may also need to add the path of the file to your settings of "Objective-C Bridging Header" in "Build Settings" -> "Swift Compiler - Code Generation" like
   MyApp/MyApp-Bridging-Header.h
   The path is relative from your project root as with your Info.plist File's path in your settings.

Comment: Yes i tried this way but didnt work for me. Hope it helps others. My current solution is to not use cocoapods for Google